# Prisma: how to write transaction where results from one query are used by another query

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma-transaction

I'm working on a project with Next.js and Prisma. In one of my API routes, I have a three queries. The results of the first and second queries are used in the third query. **I'd like to do all three operations as a transaction and then return the data from the first query in the response.**

I'm familiar with using `prisma.$transaction` but I don't know how to write it in this case where results #1 and #2 are used by query #3. Here are the queries as they are written now. Thanks in advance!

```
const { boardId } = req.body
const { description, status, title } = req.body.task

const createTask = await prisma.task.create({
  data: {
    board: boardId,
    description,
    status,
    title
  }
})

const statusArray = await prisma.board.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: boardId
  },
  select: {
    [status]: true
  }
})

const updateBoardStatusArray = await prisma.board.update({
  where: {
    id: boardId
  },
  data: {
    [status]: {
      set: [...statusArray[status], createTask.id]
    }
  }
})

// return data from first query
res.status(201).json({task: createTask})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
 const { boardId } = req.body;
  const { description, status, title } = req.body.task;

  const [createTask] = await prisma.$transaction(async (prisma) => {
    const createTask = await prisma.task.create({
      data: {
        board: boardId,
        description,
        status,
        title,
      },
    });

    const statusArray = await prisma.board.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: boardId,
      },
      select: {
        [status]: true,
      },
    });

    const updateBoardStatusArray = await prisma.board.update({
      where: {
        id: boardId,
      },
      data: {
        [status]: {
          set: [...statusArray[status], createTask.id],
        },
      },
    });
    
    return [createTask, statusArray, updateBoardStatusArray];
  });

  // return data from first query
  res.status(201).json({ task: createTask });
```

You can learn more about Interactive Transaction [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#interactive-transactions-in-preview)

Comment: Ah, I see! It's very simple. I have one more question. The value that I want to return in `res.json()` is the result of `createTask`. But it appears I cannot simply return a value, I have to return a query otherwise I get error promises.map is not a function. How can I do that?

Comment: I know how to do it, but you should update the question first then I will edit my answer too.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer too. Hope it help!